# Is the direct limit of a direct system of regular rings a regular ring?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is the direct limit of a direct system of regular rings a regular ring?

Comment: Does "direct system" mean a functor $P \to Ring$ where $P$ is a directed poset? Or just a poset, as here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit#Direct_limit_over_a_direct_system_in_a_category ?

Comment: And what do you mean by 'regular'? It is one of the most overloaded words in mathematics, even when applied to rings!

Comment: Really? The tag "algebraic geometry" probably means that we talk about commutative rings. A commutative ring is regular if it is noetherian and all its localizations are regular, and a regular local ring is defined be a noetherian local ring $(A,\mathfrak{m},k)$ such that $\dim(A)=\dim_k(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2)$.

Comment: Martin: if that was the question, the very first example that comes to mind is a counterexample: under the usual definitions the limit of the rings $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ under the obvious inclusions is not regular.

Comment: Perhaps a better title?

Comment: Martin and Mariano, I think you are both right: it's not clear as Mariano says, but likely it is what Martin says, and the answer is also already given. Lots of +1 for the comments.   

Comment: (Just edited the title)

Comment: @Mariano: a reasonable definition of regular commutative rings exists in the non-Noetherian setting: every finitely presented module admits a finite projective resolution (but you don't require projective dimension to be bounded, of course). Then a filtered colimit of regular rings under flat maps is again regular.

Comment: @Moosbrugger, Yup, I know. That's my favorite definition, in fact :) But that's not the usual definition which Martin mentioned. I asked for the definition the OP had in mind precisely to be able to know what exactly the OP had in mind: otherwise, we can but guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean regular von Nuemann with regular, then yes, a references should be  Berrick & Keating, Categories and Modules.

Comment: In fact, for directed colimits it is obvious that von Neumann regularity passes to the limit: a ring is vN regular iff for every $a$ in the ring there is a $b$ such that $a=aba$, and this kind of condition plays very nicely with colimits.